# Binding a table in polymer.dart

Tags: dart, polymer

I'm having trouble binding a model to a table if I'm not using a custom element.
Custom element works fine, but when I try to bind the model manually without creating a custom component, no data is displayed. Any Ideas?

custom_table.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>    
    <polymer-element name="custom-table" extends="div" apply-author-styles>            
      <template>      
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr template repeat="{{people}}">
              <td>{{firstName}}</td>
              <td>{{lastName}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </template>      
      <script type="application/dart" src="custom_table.dart"></script>
    </polymer-element>   
  </body>
</html>
```

custom_table.dart

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class Person  {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;        
  Person(this.firstName, this.lastName);
}

@CustomTag('custom-table')
class CustomTable extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  List people = [new Person('Bob', 'Smith'), new Person('Alice', 'Johnson')];
}
```

No custom element version:

polymer_test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>        
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="polymer_test.css">
  </head>
  <body>   
   <h1> Table test </h1>
    <template id="tableTemplate" repeat>
      <table>       
        <tbody>
          <tr template repeat="{{ people }}">
            <td>{{firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{lastName}}</td>
          <tr>            
        </tbody>  
      </table>
    </template>    
    <script type="application/dart" src="polymer_test.dart"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

polymer_test.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:fancy_syntax/syntax.dart';

class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;        
  Person(this.firstName, this.lastName);
}

class Message extends Object with ObservableMixin {  
  List<Person> people = toObservable([new Person('Bob', 'Smith'), new Person('Alice', 'Johnson')]);
}

main() {
  var msgModel = new Message();  
  TemplateElement template = query('#tableTemplate');
  template.bindingDelegate = new FancySyntax();
  template.model = msgModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind attribute was missing in my template definition. Instead, I wrongly used repeat.
It should be:

```html
<template id="tableTemplate" bind>
```

Instead of:

```html
<template id="tableTemplate" repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it help to add this to main?

```dart
void main() {
  initPolymer([], () {
    // put existing main code in here
  });
}
```

polymer/boot.js should do this, but I think right now it isn't kicking in unless the page has at least one polymer-element (this is a bug).

alternatively, you could add a dummy `<polymer-element>` to the HTML. That will workaround the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help, unless I messed something up.

Comment: I tried 3 options: adding inline polymer-element, adding custom element and initPolymer() in main(). Dummy elements work correctly, but the table does not.

Comment: for me void main() { initPolymer(); .. stuff .. } worked. DarEditor says initPolymer has 0 arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```dart
templateBind(query('#tableTemplate'))
    ..bindingDelegate = new FancySyntax()
    ..model = msgModel;
```

See http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/template_binding.html#templateBind